# same app, works on 2.2 up to 3.3 Android version but doesn't work on Android 4.0 and above

Tags: android, video, version, compatibility

I'm testing a simple app, that use VideoView to play an http/rtsp video from internet. The app works fine into 2.2 versions up to 3.3, but when i test it on 4.0 and higher, crash!!! (tested both, on the emulator and real mobile :-/)

Can anyone give me a hint why?

xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText android:id="@+id/path"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <VideoView android:id="@+id/surface_view"
                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </VideoView>
    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            >
                    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/play"
                     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                     android:src="@drawable/play"/>
    </LinearLayout>    

</LinearLayout>
```

java file:

```
  public class Video extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "VideoViewDemo";

    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private EditText mPath;
    private ImageButton mPlay;

    private Uri current;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.video);
        mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

        mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
        mPath.setText("http://daily3gp.com/vids/747.3gp");

        playVideo();

        mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);

        mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                playVideo();
            }
        });

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                playVideo();

            }

        });
    }

    private void playVideo() {
        try {
            //final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
            Uri path = Uri.parse(mPath.getText().toString());
            Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
            if (path == null) {
                Toast.makeText(Video.this, "File URL/path is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {
                // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
                if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                    mVideoView.start();
                    mVideoView.requestFocus();
                    return;
                }
                current = path;
                mVideoView.setVideoURI(path);
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();

            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    }


}
```

here the Logcat file with the erros:

```
    11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538): Activity com.testing.interacciones.Video has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413fb820 that was originally added here
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.testing.interacciones.Video has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@413fb820 that was originally added here
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:343)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:245)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:193)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:118)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:537)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:274)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:932)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.widget.VideoView$4.onError(VideoView.java:382)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.widget.VideoView.openVideo(VideoView.java:240)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.widget.VideoView.access$2000(VideoView.java:49)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.widget.VideoView$6.surfaceCreated(VideoView.java:465)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.SurfaceView.updateWindow(SurfaceView.java:562)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.SurfaceView.access$000(SurfaceView.java:82)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.SurfaceView$3.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:171)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:590)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1596)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2418)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-09 17:25:32.582: E/WindowManager(538):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 17:25:38.494: D/ExchangeService(421): Received deviceId from Email app: androidc259148960
11-09 17:25:38.494: D/ExchangeService(421): Reconciling accounts...
11-09 17:25:40.621: W/ThrottleService(93): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
11-09 17:28:46.553: D/dalvikvm(177): GC_CONCURRENT freed 458K, 6% free 10347K/10951K, paused 7ms+8ms
11-09 17:28:48.562: I/dalvikvm(93): Jit: resizing JitTable from 4096 to 8192
11-09 17:30:29.982: I/Process(538): Sending signal. PID: 538 SIG: 9
11-09 17:30:30.122: I/ActivityManager(93): Process com.testing.interacciones (pid 538) has died.
11-09 17:30:30.132: W/InputDispatcher(93): channel '41650408 com.testing.interacciones/com.testing.interacciones.Splash (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x8
11-09 17:30:30.132: E/InputDispatcher(93): channel '41650408 com.testing.interacciones/com.testing.interacciones.Splash (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
```

my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.testing.interacciones"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        

        <activity
            android:name=".Video"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>        

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The crash error on the mobile just say "Unfortunately, Test VideoView has stopped"

Thx in advance!

Comment: you must post a log first

Comment: Give me an L! Give me an O! Give me a G! Give me a C! Give me an A! Give me a T!

Comment: Hi, in order to help you, you need to add some details. On what line do you get the crash? Also add the crash log. And you might even want to add your manifest file, since it includes some data that relevant to the Android version that your app is running on.

Comment: Is possible that are doing network operation on UI thread? Because that could be a cause... Please add your logcat.

Comment: What is the error you are getting, kindly scan your logcat and provide us pointers.

Comment: @sabadow That would result in a NetworkOnMainThreadException, which is not the case. It'd also be happening on Android 3.0, which it isn't in OP's case.

Comment: It seems like OP is leaking a dialog. Try to remove any code regarding that dialog window.

Comment: @MichellBak what's OP? (sorry but i'm a bit new on Android)

Comment: @user1812260 "Original Poster", i.e. you :-)